# Need to send response after forEach is done

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working with NodeJS + Mongoose and I'm trying to populate an array of objects and then send it to the client, but I can't do it, response is always empty because it is sent before forEach ends.

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
Order.find({ seller: req.session.passport.user }, function(err, orders) {
    //handle error
      var response = [];
      orders.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.populate('customer', function(err, order) {
          //handle error
          response.push(order);
        });
      });
      res.json(response);
  });
});
```

Is there any way to send it after the loop has finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you could use any solution for async control flow management like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or promises (see [**laggingreflex**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832818/1202461) for details), but I would recommend you to use specialized Mongoose methods to populate the whole array in one MongoDB query.

The most straightforward solution is to use [`Query#populate` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) to get already populated documents:

```
Order.find({
  seller: req.session.passport.user
}).populate('customer').exec(function(err, orders) {
  //handle error
  res.json(orders);
});
```

But if, for some reason, you can't use this method, you could call [`Model.populate` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) yourself to populate an array of already fetched docs:

```
Order.populate(orders, [{
  path: 'customer'
}], function(err, populated) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: That's it. `Query#populate` works like charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use Promises.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisifyAll(Order);

router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    Order.findAsync({ seller: req.session.passport.user })
    .then(function(orders) {
        return Promise.all(orders.map(function(doc){
            return Promise.promisify(doc.populate).bind(doc)('customer');
        }));
    }).then(function(orders){
        // You might also wanna convert them to JSON
        orders = orders.map(function(doc){ return doc.toJSON() });
        res.json(orders);
    }).catch(function(err){
        //handle error
    });
});
```

[BlueBird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyallobject-target--object-options---object)'s `.promisifyAll` creates an `…Async` version of all functions of an object, which saves you an extra step in configuring the initial promise. So instead of `Order.find` I used `Order.findAsync` in above example

Comment: I didn't know about promises because I'm a total noob with NodeJS. I'll look into them and bluebird too. Thank you so much too!